# Bootstrap setting height for btn-block buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-block" href="#">1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-block" href="#">2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
      <a class="btn btn-default btn-block" href="#">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This gives me 3 buttons across which is what I want. What I would like to do is make the buttons taller. If at all possible I'd prefer not to specify heights in pixels so that it can scale to different screen sizes better. Could I perhaps specify the height as a ratio (of the width) or a percentage of screen height?

Comment: Not sure why I got down-voted on this. It was a genuine question that I didn't know the answer for as I'm a new Bootstrap user. I searched both Google and Stack Overflow and couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simple & best solution would be to add top and bottom padding.

```
.btn-block {
    padding: 10% 0; 
    /* define values in pixels / Percentage or em. whatever suits 
       your requirements */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works well. When I specify 10% as in your code above, what is it 10% of?

Comment: it will be of the button but it was just a dummy value the best thing would be to define in EM.

Answer (score 7):

Use Bootstrap padding property p-.  [Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/)

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-block p-3" href="#">1</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, just use `py-4` as an extra class on your button.

`py-#` adds padding on top and bottom at the same time, and you can choose how much by changing the number (I think the max is 4, but I might be wrong).

You can check all the options [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/#notation) (it works at least from Bootstrap 4 onwards).